# System.FormatException running .NET Framework 2.0 from 4.7

Tags: c#, .net

Bonjour, i'm trying to run an external .exe compiled with .Net framework 2.0 inside a wpf application 4.7.2

Running exe outside the application it works correctly from command prompt 64 bit and 32 bit

Inside the application, can't start

I tried to change the Platform Target to 32bit but nothing changed
This is my simple code

Attach the report error from event viewer
[LINK](https://gxitalia-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/p/matteo_beretta/ERzYoXYy4XlOl0TbIk5iPWIBJsqQuekNVGfKqwmKmeRpWw?e=KAjozn)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(@"D:\VSOnline\AZM\UI\Dll\REC\ucauavacom.exe");
    }
}


Version=1
EventType=CLR20r3
EventTime=132011076783616260
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=132011076784902815
ReportStatus=268435456
ReportIdentifier=6cb34329-4a71-4ab7-a974-14a77773fb82
Wow64Host=34404
Wow64Guest=332
OriginalFilename=ucauavacom.exe
AppSessionGuid=00000ce8-0004-0008-b9b8-fdf95fffd401
TargetAppId=W:00065aa8e3c53f2f0438188224566e08d7c400000000!0000653bf4303bfe4278760dc1f81e01af9b1a61e88f!ucauavacom.exe
TargetAppVer=2019//04//29:07:14:07!0!ucauavacom.exe
BootId=4294967295
TargetAsId=11516
IsFatal=4294967295
EtwNonCollectReason=1
Response.BucketId=c7751f8b64a5bd8e12d5b207b5b17a45
Response.BucketTable=5
Response.LegacyBucketId=1357186608904895045
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Problem Signature 01
Sig[0].Value=ucauavacom.exe
Sig[1].Name=Problem Signature 02
Sig[1].Value=0.0.0.0
Sig[2].Name=Problem Signature 03
Sig[2].Value=5cc6a43f
Sig[3].Name=Problem Signature 04
Sig[3].Value=mscorlib
Sig[4].Name=Problem Signature 05
Sig[4].Value=2.0.0.0
Sig[5].Name=Problem Signature 06
Sig[5].Value=5b8769e1
Sig[6].Name=Problem Signature 07
Sig[6].Value=c4e
Sig[7].Name=Problem Signature 08
Sig[7].Value=59
Sig[8].Name=Problem Signature 09
Sig[8].Value=System.FormatException
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.17763.2.0.0.256.4
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
UI[2]=D:\VSOnline\VulpesAZMEC\UI\Dll\Genexus\ucauavacom.exe
LoadedModule[0]=D:\VSOnline\VulpesAZMEC\UI\Dll\Genexus\ucauavacom.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\System32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\System32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.9554_none_d08d6fa2442aa556\MSVCR80.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\ff1d144ce21afb2aa98cad685cd5645a\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System\d7298a5015ba68c23f00471d6b82e406\System.ni.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\vjslib\2b0d8525e3b91031192b172be15bf5a0\vjslib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[41]=D:\VSOnline\VulpesAZMEC\UI\Dll\Genexus\gxclassrDotNet.dll
LoadedModule[42]=D:\VSOnline\VulpesAZMEC\UI\Dll\Genexus\GxClasses.dll
LoadedModule[43]=D:\VSOnline\VulpesAZMEC\UI\Dll\Genexus\tabelle.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\vjsnativ.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\diasymreader.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Data\9f1a2a66adfaad4035e76ac9e9dc4752\System.Data.ni.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\System32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\System32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Drawing\79540f484951ac659ecd1f4b83fd7b83\System.Drawing.ni.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\vjscor\921ca78ff832b6b7cbd852cea314e17d\vjscor.ni.dll
LoadedModule[55]=D:\VSOnline\VulpesAZMEC\UI\Dll\Genexus\log4net.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Configuration\3c344944cef7cb6aa601ef93c35559cc\System.Configuration.ni.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Xml\625f15f169750dff26ab86b4540eadf0\System.Xml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Management\2e66417e8c85e02597fb5dadd0d7e84d\System.Management.ni.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WININET.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ondemandconnroutehelper.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\winhttp.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\Windows\System32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
LoadedModule[67]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Web\63e898df2d023e3a225a241eba37aa21\System.Web.ni.dll
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
OsInfo[0].Key=vermaj
OsInfo[0].Value=10
OsInfo[1].Key=vermin
OsInfo[1].Value=0
OsInfo[2].Key=verbld
OsInfo[2].Value=17763
OsInfo[3].Key=ubr
OsInfo[3].Value=437
OsInfo[4].Key=versp
OsInfo[4].Value=0
OsInfo[5].Key=arch
OsInfo[5].Value=9
OsInfo[6].Key=lcid
OsInfo[6].Value=2057
OsInfo[7].Key=geoid
OsInfo[7].Value=118
OsInfo[8].Key=sku
OsInfo[8].Value=4
OsInfo[9].Key=domain
OsInfo[9].Value=1
OsInfo[10].Key=prodsuite
OsInfo[10].Value=256
OsInfo[11].Key=ntprodtype
OsInfo[11].Value=1
OsInfo[12].Key=platid
OsInfo[12].Value=10
OsInfo[13].Key=sr
OsInfo[13].Value=0
OsInfo[14].Key=tmsi
OsInfo[14].Value=24429
OsInfo[15].Key=osinsty
OsInfo[15].Value=2
OsInfo[16].Key=iever
OsInfo[16].Value=11.437.17763.0-11.0.120
OsInfo[17].Key=portos
OsInfo[17].Value=0
OsInfo[18].Key=ram
OsInfo[18].Value=15919
OsInfo[19].Key=svolsz
OsInfo[19].Value=356
OsInfo[20].Key=wimbt
OsInfo[20].Value=0
OsInfo[21].Key=blddt
OsInfo[21].Value=180914
OsInfo[22].Key=bldtm
OsInfo[22].Value=1434
OsInfo[23].Key=bldbrch
OsInfo[23].Value=rs5_release
OsInfo[24].Key=bldchk
OsInfo[24].Value=0
OsInfo[25].Key=wpvermaj
OsInfo[25].Value=0
OsInfo[26].Key=wpvermin
OsInfo[26].Value=0
OsInfo[27].Key=wpbuildmaj
OsInfo[27].Value=0
OsInfo[28].Key=wpbuildmin
OsInfo[28].Value=0
OsInfo[29].Key=osver
OsInfo[29].Value=10.0.17763.437.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434
OsInfo[30].Key=buildflightid
OsInfo[31].Key=edition
OsInfo[31].Value=Enterprise
OsInfo[32].Key=ring
OsInfo[33].Key=expid
OsInfo[34].Key=containerid
OsInfo[35].Key=containertype
OsInfo[36].Key=edu
OsInfo[36].Value=0
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=CLR20r3
AppName=ucauavacom.exe
AppPath=D:\VSOnline\VulpesAZMEC\UI\Dll\Genexus\ucauavacom.exe
ReportDescription=Stopped working
ApplicationIdentity=00000000000000000000000000000000
MetadataHash=-1204513862
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete exception details?

Comment: i've attached a link with the report error from event viewer

Comment: Please post the exception details, like message and stack trace, in the question itself.

Comment: I have no exception inside my application, because i'm trying just to run An external exe, so i don't have any exception inside my app.

Comment: Please post the contents of the linked file in the question itself.  Everything needed to answer the question should be *in* the question.

Comment: Ok sorry, posted

Comment: Try setting working directory as well, it may be that the program expects a certain working directory in order to function. Unfortunately, if you don't have access to the source code of that application, there's not much help we can provide other than "ooh, that's too bad". Can you try running it from inside Visual Studio and attaching to it or something, to see if you can debug it?

Comment: One way to debug it could be to set that file path as the "external program" in the debugging options for your project, this would debug that executable instead of your own, you might then enable "break on all exceptions" and see if the exception object inside the application contains something useful.

Comment: Thanks Lasse, it works setting working directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that both applications `A.exe` and `B.exe` use a dll with the same name `C.dll` which is present in different versions in the two directories where the executables are stored.

If you start `B.exe` from `A.exe`, by default, the directory of `A.exe` is the current working directory and B.exe will try to load `C.dll` from that directory, which fails.

Specify the correct working directory when starting the application.

```
string executable = @"D:\VSOnline\AZM\UI\Dll\REC\ucauavacom.exe";
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = executable;
info.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(executable);

Process.Start(info);
```